# REST API oauth2 type authentication using AWS Cognito

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I have a rest api in nodejs. my mobile app will consume my rest api. Can i implement oauth2 type authentication using aws cognito for my mobile app? I need resource owner password grant if i implement oauth2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amazon Cognito's [Federated Identity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-identity.html) feature is not an authentication provider. It vends AWS credentials for well known providers like Facebook, Google, Cognito User Pools, etc. or for custom developer providers. These custom developer provider can use any authentication protocol as long as they talk to our services from the back end and use the OpenId tokens vended in back end from their mobile apps. You can read more about this [here](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en).

[Cognito User Pools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html) however is an authentication provider and vends OpenId tokens once the user is authenticated. These tokens can also be exchanged for AWS credentials using the federated identity flow.

Comment: is there any documentation to help with OAuth2 integration?